# How to draw many diagonal lines[right hash lines] using css, html?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How to draw many diagonal lines within rectangle in the beginning using css, html?
I want to draw diagonal lines in the beginning of the rectangle.

I could display the rectangle using below Code:

```
<div className={moneybarsection.bar1} />

.bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
  }

  .bar1 {
    @extend .bar;
    background: #24891D;
    border-left: 150px solid #6FD967;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.bar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #6FD967;
    border-right: 150px solid green;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        -45deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 4px,
        transparent 1px,
        green 7px
      ),
      linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        transparent,
        transparent
      )
  }
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mamata/q3ef8b7d/

Answer (score 0):

```
.bar {
    height: 100px;
    width: 5px;
    background: black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b38zkr53/

Using transform you can create diagonal line.

Comment: Ok do it. That's the basic. Or you want the whole code to be coded for you? Loooooololololololllllll

Comment: I know to draw single diagonal line. I wanted to know for many diagonal lines. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Use pseudo before and after or you can create another class. Loooool

Comment: The solution I provided, you can create two diagonals right now. Check it and customize according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.triangle,.triangle1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 5px;
    background: black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.triangle1{ transform: rotate(137deg);margin-left:62px;}
.triangle2{border-bottom:5px solid #000;width:20px;margin-left:200px;height:5px;}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div><div class="triangle1"></div>
<div class="triangle2">
```